# MKMapView in Swift4 Emulator not working properly?

Tags: mkmapview, swift4

What happened to MKMapView in Swift 4 Emulator?  Maybe I am doing something wrong?  This worked fine in Swift 3.  Now the map takes 5 to 8 seconds to load and each tap to zoom takes 5 seconds.  It does not scroll at all. This works fine when installed on a phone, but is just about unusable in the emulator (using iPhone 6s target at the moment).  All defined programmatically (no storyboard!). bits of the code pulled together below.  Runs fine on phone.  Is unusable in emulator and emulator gives off error messages that do not show up when running on the phone

error messages are as follows, even though i do get the scale and legal attribution, even in the emulator. Not sure if the error message at what is causing the 5+ second delay.

```
Could not inset compass from edges 9
Could not inset scale from edge 9
Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4
```

The code bits

```
    let mapview = MKMapView()

    containerView.addSubview( mapview)
    mapview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewTop.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    mapview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewTop.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    mapview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewTop.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    mapview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewTop.topAnchor, constant: 230).isActive = true

    mapview.delegate = self
    mapview.mapType = .standard
    mapview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mapview.showsCompass = true
    mapview.showsScale = true
    mapview.isScrollEnabled = true
    mapview.isZoomEnabled = true
    mapview.showsPointsOfInterest = true
```

I have no location manager. Just showing locations on a map without need for asking for user location.

Comment: What is a Swift 4 emulator? Are you talking about an iOS 11 simulator versus earlier iOS simulators?

Comment: yes iOS11 simulator.  Seems this is a duplicate (noted and linked) - known bug in simulator. Although I get different error messages. Hopefully when the fix goes in, the performance is usable and my error messages go away.